# Can't change login name on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop

Tags: 16.04

I installed ubuntu 16.04 `desktop` on USB flash drive and setup an `autologin` during installation. The PC boots up and auto login successfully before I performed some system update for video driver installation. Now the system boots up and presents a login screen with a different user name which there is no password associated with and can't be changed. I can hit `ctrl+alt+F1` to switch to a terminal screen but can't start X window with `startx`.

My question is how to login with a different user name on login screen?

Here is the login screen. Needs to login with a user other than `miner1`.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

**To change the username :**

```
sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
```

**To change the homefolder :**

```
usermod -d /home/newHomeDir -m newUsername
```

**To Change the group:**

```
groupmod -n <newgroup> <oldgroup>
```

## **To do this in one command:**

Login as root :

```
usermod -l <newname> -d /home/<newname> -m <oldname>
```

Comment: I need to use different name to login and the system does not allow to do. I don't need to change the user name.

Comment: sudo adduser newname

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed by disabling the screen lock after reinstalling the OS. Somehow the system locks the screen without revealing the password.